# Can a .json file be read from a dependent library with require()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I would like to get at a `.json` file in one of my dependent libraries.

using fs to read `./node_modules/somelib/properties.json` doesn't seem foolproof because `somelib` could have been installed globally.

Can this be done with `require`?

Comment: Be aware that the required json might be cached so if you'll require it again it will return the same result even if the file has changed.

Comment: @E.Sundin Thanks - I'm expecting the stuff in node_modules to be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with require.

Require, fetches the file and assigns the exports to the assigned variable. In this case,

```
var jsonObject = require('somelib/properties.json');
```

should assign the JSON object to `jsonObject` variable.

Comment: Thank you.   I just tried this.  It looks like the `./node_modules/` part can be left off, too.